# Cannot extract a string with variable in Substr

Tags: php, arrays, substring

$corrispondenzaCampi --> array with couple values (0,2 - 4,2 - ecc) (start,length).

$aryText --> 11010230010230

```
foreach($corrispondenzaCampi as $corrispondenza)
    {
        echo $corrispondenza."<br><br>";
        echo substr($aryText,$corrispondenza)."<br><br>";
        echo substr($aryText,0,2);
        die();
        if($c == 0)
        {
            $aryValori = "'".substr($aryText,$corrispondenza)."'";
        }
        else
        {
            $aryValori = ",'".substr($aryText,$corrispondenza)."'";
        }
        $c++;
    }
```

OUTPUT PROBLEM:

```
$corrispondenza --> 0,2

substr($aryText,$corrispondenza) --> 11010230010230

substr($aryText,0,2) --> 11
```

Can someone tell me why of this result?

Comment: What is `aryText`?

Comment: and which part of the output is the problem? what are you expecting?

Comment: can you give an example of the value in **$corrispondenzaCampi** ?

Comment: I write everything you asked at the end

Comment: $corrispondenzaCampi is an array containing couple values like 1,2 or 4,2 (start,length)

Comment: please add these infos to the question so that people dont need to skim through the comments to get the whole picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `$corrispondenza` is a string of '1,2'.

`substr($aryText, $corrispondenza)` is not the same as `substr($aryText, 1, 2)`.

`substr($aryText, $corrispondenza)` will ignore `$corrispondenza` because it's not an `int` and thereof print the whole `$aryText`.

See [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) for `substr`.